# Automapper - How to get containing class type when mapping a member?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

During a runtime mapping operation (like when you use ResolveUsing or a custom TypeConverter) is it possible to get the container classes (or types at least) of the source and destination members?

I know that when you map one object to another, that the objects don't have to be members of some "parent" or "container" object, but I'm talking about the situation when AutoMapper is recursively copying a complex object.

Here's an example:

Here I'm copying (or setting it up at least) Cars & Boats of "kind A" to "kind B".

```
public class VehicleCopyProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public VehicleCopyProfile()
    {
        this.CreateMap<CarA, CarB>();
        this.CreateMap<BoatA, BoatB>();

        this.CreateMap<WindshieldA, WindshieldB>(
            .ConvertUsing((s, d, resContext) =>
            {
                // *** How can I tell if s is coming from a Car or a Boat? ***
            });

    }
}

// Cars & Boats each have a Windshield

public class CarA
{
    public WindshieldA Windshield {get;set;}
}

public class BoatA
{
    public WindshieldA Windshield {get;set;}
}

public class WindshieldA
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}





public class CarB
{
    public WindshieldB Windshield {get;set;}
}

public class BoatB
{
    public WindshieldB Windshield {get;set;}
}


public class WindshieldB
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Better now? ...

Comment: You cannot. But you can pass the root object through context.Items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using AutoMapper ResolutionContext Items as proposed by [@Lucian Bargaoanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811700/lucian-bargaoanu) in comment. The idea is to use Before and After Map to store information in the Resolution Context. I use a Stack to keep track of the whole chain of relationship.

```
namespace SO51101306
{
    public static class IMappingExpressionExtensions
    {
        public static IMappingExpression<A, B> RegisterChainOfTypes<A, B>(this IMappingExpression<A, B> mapping)
        {
            mapping.BeforeMap((a, b, ctx) => {
                ctx.PushTypeInChainOfTypes(typeof(A));
            });

            mapping.AfterMap((a, b, ctx) => {
                ctx.PopLastTypeInChainOfTypes();
            });
            return mapping;
        }
    }

    public static class ResolutionContextExtensions
    {
        const string chainOfTypesKey = "ChainOfTypes";

        private static Stack<Type> GetOrCreateChainOfTypesStack(ResolutionContext ctx)
        {
            var hasKey = ctx.Items.ContainsKey(chainOfTypesKey);
            return hasKey ? (Stack<Type>)ctx.Items[chainOfTypesKey] : new Stack<Type>();
        }

        public static void PushTypeInChainOfTypes(this ResolutionContext ctx, Type type)
        {
            var stack = GetOrCreateChainOfTypesStack(ctx);
            stack.Push(type);
            ctx.Items[chainOfTypesKey] = stack;
        }

        public static Type PopLastTypeInChainOfTypes(this ResolutionContext ctx)
        {
            var stack = (Stack<Type>)ctx.Items[chainOfTypesKey];
            return stack.Pop();
        }

        public static bool HasParentType(this ResolutionContext ctx, Type parentType)
        {
            var stack = GetOrCreateChainOfTypesStack(ctx);
            return stack.Contains(parentType);
        }

    }

    public class CarCopyProfile : Profile
    {
        public CarCopyProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<CarA, CarB>().RegisterChainOfTypes();
            CreateMap<BoatA, BoatB>().RegisterChainOfTypes();

            CreateMap<WindshieldA, WindshieldB>()
            .ConvertUsing((wa,wb,ctx)=> {
                if(ctx.HasParentType(typeof(CarA)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("I'm coming from CarA");
                    //Do specific stuff here
                }
                else if (ctx.HasParentType(typeof(BoatA)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("I'm coming from boatA");
                    //Do specific stuff here
                }
                return wb;
            });

        }
    }

    public class CarA
    {
        public WindshieldA Windshield { get; set; }
    }

    public class BoatA
    {
        public WindshieldA Windshield { get; set; }
    }

    public class CarB
    {
        public WindshieldB Windshield { get; set; }
    }

    public class BoatB
    {
        public WindshieldB Windshield { get; set; }
    }

    public class WindshieldA
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class WindshieldB
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(c => c.AddProfile<CarCopyProfile>());

            var carA = new CarA{Windshield = new WindshieldA()};
            var boatA = new BoatA{Windshield = new WindshieldA()};

            var carB = Mapper.Map<CarB>(carA);
            var boatB = Mapper.Map<BoatB>(boatA);
        }
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
I'm coming from CarA
I'm coming from boatA
```

Comment: Unless someone else replies I will mark this as the best answer within 2 days. I think that "ResolutionContext.Items" and BeforeMap are the keys to this problem. But if you want to make a general solution you need to do more than this. You see, if your Windshield classes, themselves, have a subclass, this won't work. In my final solution, for every CreateMap, you add the source type to a chain of source types in the CreateMap.BeforeMap method. Then you use AfterMap to "pop" that source type from the chain. The parent type will always be 2nd in the chain (except for collections, cuz of a bug).

Comment: Note: There's a bug with After/BeforeMap and Profile.IncludeBase(). If you are using these, then during a single mapping execution, After/BeforeMap will be called for each included Profile. I think After/BeforeMap is supposed to have polymorphic behavior, but it doesn't - at least with IncludeBase() - maybe it works with Include() (which includes a derived type, not a base type profile).

Comment: @N73k sure my code is a sample code and as you said, you have to take care of multiple level of relations between your object.

Comment: @N73k I made it more general with a Stack so that it should handle multiple level of relationship

Comment: Thanks for the update. Better. I'm marking it as the answer. But still, a couple of problems. 

1. I think you are confusing "parent" with "ancestor". I was only asking for the container (parent) type. You can leave that code in there and just change the name "parent" to "ancestor", and then add the static method to get the parent type.

2. Your HasParentType method will include the current type also. So, if, from Windshield's ConvertUsing, I say HasParentType(typeof(WindshieldA)), the result will come back as true instead of false.

Anyway, I'll try to post my solution later.

Comment: 'Ancestor' was the word I was looking for when I wrote the code but I wasn't able to find it back :-) (I had to wrote this code during my lunch break and I didn't have a lot of time) You are right the code does not handle 100% of cases but at least it gives a good start point for people asking themself how to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to use custom value resolver:

```
class CustomResolver<T1, T2>:IValueResolver ... { ... }

this.CreateMap<CarA, CarB>()
.ForMember(x => x.Windshield , opt => opt.ResolveUsing(new CustomResolver<CarA, CarB>()));
```

Then in you `CustomResolver` implementation:

```
var windshieldB = Mapper.Map<WindshieldB>(windshieldA, x => {x.Items["type1"] = typeof(T1); x.Items["type2"] = typeof(T2);});
```

And then:

```
this.CreateMap<WindshieldA, WindshieldB>(
            .ConvertUsing((s, d, resContext) =>
            {
                // resContext.Options.Items["type1"]
            });
```

See http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer but there are a lot of problems:

1. This is hardcoded to the example
2. For every object in the graph hierarchy, you'd have to make a custom CustomResolver class
3. Every time you adjust your object hierarchy (object graph) you'd have to change the wiring of all this code.
4. By using a CustomResolver to solve this problem, you're eliminating the use of a CustomResolver for normal use.
5. If someone uses a CustomResolver (normal use), you already want to be able to know, in the CustomResolver, what the container type is.
6. Too much code you'd need to repeat.